# an identity related to Ricci tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

> If $$R_{ij,k}=2\lambda_kR_{ij}+\lambda_iR_{kj}+\lambda_jR_{ik}$$ where
> $\lambda_i$ is a covariant vector , $R_{ij}$ is Ricci tensor , show
> that $$\lambda_k=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}\log\sqrt{R}$$

Multiplying $R_{ij,k}=2\lambda_kR_{ij}+\lambda_iR_{kj}+\lambda_jR_{ik}$ both sides by $g^{ik}$ $$(g^{ik}R_{ij})_{,k}=2g^{ik}\lambda_kR_{ij}+g^{ik}\lambda_iR_{kj}+g^{ik}\lambda_jR_{ik}$$ $$\implies R^k_{j,k}=2\lambda_iR_{ij}+\lambda_kR_{kj}+\lambda_jR$$ By contracted Bianchi identity $$\frac{1}{2}R_{,j}=2\lambda_iR_{ij}+\lambda_kR_{kj}+\lambda_jR$$ Afterwards I have no idea how to proceed . Any help is appreciated .

Comment: $\lambda_iR_{ij}=\lambda_kR_{kj}$ - i and k here are mute summation indexes. You may write k instead of i and vice versa

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to fold the initial equation also by $g^{ij}$ and use symmetry $R_{kj}=R_{jk}$. You will get the second equation $R_{,k}=2\lambda_iR_{k}^{i}+2\lambda_kR$. Then multiply the first equation that you got by 2 and extract from the second one - you will get $\lambda_iR_{k}^{i}=0$ and, consequently, from the second equation: $R_{,k}=2\lambda_kR$.